# How can I list users by date in an array in meta_value?

Tags: users, user-meta, meta-value

I keep an order list of all users. I keep this list in the meta_key value named payments. The payments meta allows me to keep information about the payments the user made. To give an example for an user:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'date' => '2020-04-15',
        'amount' => '750',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'date' => '2020-04-20',
        'amount' => '900',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'type' => 'installment',
        'installments' => array(
            0 => array(
                'date' => '2020-04-20',
                'amount' => '250',
            ),
            1 => array(
                'date' => '2020-05-20',
                'amount' => '250',
            ),
            2 => array(
                'date' => '2020-06-20',
                'amount' => '250',
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Based on this information, I try to list the users who have not paid. How can I list users with a payment older than today? I tried this but it didn't:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');    
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'payments' AND meta_value <= '%".$today."%'");
```

**Alternative scenario:**

Based on the comment made by @Himand, I produced an alternative scenario. I decided to keep each of a user's payments as a separate meta_value. For example:

For user 1:

I created a metadata that holds the total number of payments: `_payments_count`

And I gave a number to each payment in order. For example: `_payment_detail_1` `_payment_detail_2` `_payment_detail_3`.

Then I created a for loop depending on the number of payments.

```
$payment_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_payments_count', true );
for ($i = 1; $i <= $payment_count ; $i++) {
    $payment_detail = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_payment_detail_'.$i, true );
}
```

This way I can access all payment data, but I just don't know what to do when I want to list older payments than today. After I pull all the payment information, I can make it list the older ones today with an if statement.  Like this:

```
$payment_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_payments_count', true );
for ($i = 1; $i <= $payment_count ; $i++) {
    $payment_detail = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_payment_detail_'.$i, true );
    if ( $payment_detail['payment_date'] < date('Y-m-d') ){
        // ......
    }
}
```

However, this means a big loss of performance. Because there are thousands of users registered in the system. I want to list the payments by comparing the date information directly.

Anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: The way you're doing it is not optimal for search queries, you should have a separate meta entry for each payment record.

Comment: @Himad Thank you for your suggestion. So if I keep the payment information as you say, how can I sort past payments by date?

Comment: @Himad Based on your comment, I added an alternative scenario. Is it possible for you to review?

Comment: Using a separate meta key for each payment is not optimal at all. Ideally, you would treat a payment as a custom post type. The post creation date is the payment date, the author is the user who made the payment and then all you'd have to do is add a custom meta field to the post representing the payment amount. After that, you can search your payments using a WP_Query which can be configured to search by date.

Comment: @Himad Thank you for your interest and for your descriptive answers. Payments can be both in cash and in installments. In installment payment types, I keep the payment date of each installment separately. In this case, it is impossible to keep the installment date as post creation date. Because payment dates may be in the future, now or in the past. Do you have any idea for this situation? I added an example of installment payment to the question.

Comment: Then just use a custom meta field for the date instead of the default post_date field.

Comment: @Himad So let's go back to our main problem. Let's imagine that we have created a post for each payment. We created a custom field for the payment date. What will we do for installment payments? We will need to create a date for each installment. And what I really want is to list the out-of-date payments.

Comment: You'd use a WP_Query to get a list of all posts where `'post_type'=>'payment'` and the meta value `payment_date` is smaller than the actual date. You can find plenty of examples of such queries.

Comment: @Himad Of course I can do that. This is pretty simple. However, there is a point that I do not understand. Will I create a post for each installment? Isn't that unnecessary? Is it optimal to create a post for each installment while keeping it in one metadata?

Comment: Yes. a 'post' can be seen as a single unit of anything. WooCommerce represents products with a custom post type, for example. Relational databases rely on connections across entries. By working this way, you can take advantage of WP_Query which already handles the search process of any type of post. That way you don't have to directly perform SQL queries.

Comment: @Himad So how do I relate installment payments? 1st installment, 2nd installment etc.